# Как посмотреть, какие __ctype есть в .so?

Tags: linux, c

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быстро посмотреть все __ctype в какой-либо .so?

Comment: Что такое `__ctype` и зачем их смотреть?

Comment: функция такая...

Answer (score 0):

`nm /full/path/to/so | grep __ctype` - Один из вариантов.